# MySQL: Order by column if exist in other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1. `users`(userID, name, location, type, etc)
2. `onlineusers` (userID, status, etc)

I want to list all the `users` where type = `'sometype'` and order these `users` in asc but **first** all users exist in `onlineusers` table then those that are not in `onlineusers` table.

I have managed to get all the onlineusers first but they are not in asc order.

This is what I tried

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN onlineusers o on u.userID = o.userID
where u.type = 'sometype' 
order by IFNULL(o.userID,9999) desc;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN onlineusers o on u.userID = o.userID
where u.type = 'sometype' 
order by o.userID is null,
         u.userID
```

`o.userID is null` returns `1` (true) for users that are not online and `0` (false) if they are. You can order by these 2 values.